# Which grows slower: the thumb nail or the pinky nail?

Tags: human-biology

I notice that thumb nails and pinky nails grow slower than the 3 other fingers in the middle. But which one is slower, the thumb nail or the pinky nail?

Comment: This isn't at all my experience - it seems this may vary. I'm sure apparent growth also depends on "usage".

Comment: Biology Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for biology researchers, academics, and students. This question is of freak-show triviality. I have voted to close it.

Comment: @David There are many papers on the subject. Bean wrote 4 papers on fingernail growth that are considered important medical findings.

Comment: Which one is slower? "Important medical findings"? Mr Bean?

Comment: Your question would be better if you summarized relevant said research. It's also probably prudent not to call other people sssholes.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and found out that it is actually the pinky that grows the slowest. See the decadal reports of Bean on fingernail growth or:

Gupta, Gita Rani, et al. "Human nail growth pattern and medicolegal aspect." (2005).

Comment: So how are you going to use this information? If you really think it is worthy of anyone's attention, cite references it in a way that someone else can consult them. You need proper journal etc details with a link of some sort.